# using sphinx autosummary extension with matlab domain

Tags: matlab, python-sphinx

I'm trying to use the [Sphinx matlab domain](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sphinxcontrib-matlabdomain) with the autosummary extension to generate documentation for several MATLAB functions in a toolbox. The ReST file in the docs for these functions looks like this:

```
.. currentmodule:: mytoolbox

.. autosummary::
    :toctree: generated/
    :nosignatures:

    func1
```

Although I have `matlab_src_dir` set to the correct base directory containing the toolbox subdirectory and `autosummary_generate` set to True, the autosummary extension emits a warning indicating that it "failed to import 'mytoolbox.func1': no module named mytoolbox.func1". Does the autosummary extension work with the MATLAB domain? If so, what might I be misconfiguring? My `conf.py` file contains the following:

```
import sys, os

extensions = ['sphinxcontrib.matlab',
              'sphinx.ext.pngmath',
              'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
              'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
              'sphinx.ext.autosummary']

needs_sphinx = '1.0'
templates_path = ['_templates']
autosummary_generate = True
source_suffix = '.rst'
master_doc = 'index'
language = 'en'
exclude_patterns = ['build']
pygments_style = 'sphinx'
matlab_src_dir = os.path.abspath('../../')
on_rtd = os.environ.get('READTHEDOCS', None) == 'True'

if on_rtd:
    html_theme = 'default'
else:
    import sphinx_rtd_theme
    html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'
    html_theme_path = [sphinx_rtd_theme.get_html_theme_path()]
html_domain_indices = False
html_use_index = True
```

Comment: What does your file structure look like? Point `matlab_src_dir` at folder above `mytoolbox` also make sure `func1.m` exists.

Comment: I believe I am doing that - for a base directory `basedir`, the MATLAB files (`func1.m`) are located in `basedir/mytoolbox`; the Sphinx ReST files and `conf.py` file are stored in `basedir/docs/source`, and I verified that `basedir/mytoolbox/func1.m` exists.

Comment: I should also have mentioned that I am using Sphinx 1.2.3 and sphinxcontrib-matlabdomain 0.2.6 with Python 2.7.6.

Comment: @lebedov Have you tried setting the default domain? I think it might default to `.py`...

Comment: Setting `primary_domain = 'mat'` did not appear to have any effect on the autosummary generation.

Comment: Sorry, but evidently the `autosummary` extension will not work with the present version of `sphinxcontrib.matlabdomain`. I took a very brief look at it, and it may take a while for me to implement. If anyone else has the time, contributions are welcomed.